# Low budget D-list movie with werewolf, emo guy, and mystical girl of his dreams

Tags: horror, story-identification, movie

This is one for the pros. I'm trying to identify this movie, not because it was good or because I want to re-watch it, but because it was one of the most steaming piles of cinematic crud that I'd ever seen in Netflix (or possibly Amazon Prime). I'll try my best to give the bits and pieces I remember.

So yes, it was streamed, either Netflix or Amazon Prime video. It was within the last 5 years, or so.

Opening title screens had a very anime-like quality, very CGI heavy and felt like a kind of video game production. The film used **low quality CGI** often for things like fire and magic stuff.

Early scenes had a girl being chased down by a wolf or wolves, and at least one of them transforming into his human form. One of the werewolves was a black guy. The wolves might have chosen a new alpha at this point; or there was some kind of transfer or establishment of werewolf authority.

Later there was a teen party scene where an emo 'Azn' dude (a white guy who wanted to look Asian) and his buddy were talking about the girls, and the emo dude was very much a introvert/nerd, being razzed by his buddy for it. This dude fell for a girl with some kind of mystical qualities. She showed up **in his dreams**, at first. And then later they'd  meet in reality.

There was a big fight scene between the black guy werewolf and one or two others, I think involving the emo dude and the mystical girl. The werewolf had some awful cheesy lines and over-the-top gloating & power-tripping. The emo dude may have been trying to save the girl from the werewolf. But I can't remember if he had any powers of his own. The girl did use some powers of some kind.

The dialogue was largely sloppy and half-baked; not immature or sophomoric, just really corny. The action was poorly done and the actors often sounded bored, except the werewolf who was sometimes way too enthusiastic, especially during the big fight.

This isn't meant to be a review, I'm just at a loss for more pertinent details. I hope that someone else out there has seen this and can relate.

Comment: Not *The Howling: Reborn*? Could never bring myself to watch the whole thing, but vaguely recall it has the same vibe.

Comment: @Walt nope.. nice try though, appreciate the thought, especially given how old the question is. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. I have a good news that I know exactly the movie that you were looking for. It's called [*Dark Moon Rising*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3155734/) (2015) ---It is supposedly the sequel to Dark Moon Rising (2009)-I know it's not a creative name for a sequel, as you've mentioned before that it's a D-grade movie.

There's a funny story why I was looking for "Dark Moon Rising (2015)" as well. It's because of this awesome song called "You Got Me" by Breaking Through, that played when emo 'Azn' dude had a breakup with his mystical girlfriend.

It's kinda funny that both of us were looking for same movie. Anyways hope my answer help no matter how late it is.

Comment: Nice, this looks like a good fit!

Comment: Yup, David. This is exactly the trailer of the movie ( Dark Moon Rising 2015) that was required by NathanJ. Kudos for finding the exact trailer.

Comment: OMG! That's IT!! Fantastic work my dude (or lady). But seriously, anybody else who views this, don't trust the trailer, the movie is absolute trash. ;o]

Comment: You're welcome Nate. But you should also thank DavidW as well for giving imdb link to the movie and it's trailer. Yup, the movie was an absolute trash. It felt like Asylum Film making mockbuster version of twilight 